# Determine the CN and time comlexity for the recurrence function

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

```
public static int test(int N) {
  if (N == 1) return 1; 
  return (3 * (test(N/2) + test(N/2)) + f(N)) 
}

public static void f(int a) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++) 
  System.out.println(“algo rocks”);
}
```

I was trying to determine the CN and the complexity for the code above

I came to this conclusion

- C<sub>1</sub> = 0 --> the terminating condition
- C<sub>N</sub> = 2C<sub>N/2</sub> + N

I was lost with this 3 that the functions are multiplied with can you please check my work and guide me where it is wrong.

Comment: in the code if N is not equal to 1, the test fxn is called twice and there is a multiplication for the result with 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're wrong in claiming that C(1) = 0, it is 1 actually.

So, C(1) = 1.

Also, time complexity of function f() in worst case comes out to be `O(N)`, since N is being passed out to the function.

So, your recurrence relation turns out to be :

```
T(N) = 3 * 2 * T(N/2) + O(N)
     = 6 T(N/2) + O(N).
```

I am leaving the recurrence relation for you to solve. It's easy. If you're unable to calculate, ping below this answer after trying once at least.

Comment: I guess I need to suppose that N =2^n 
right??
Am I on the right track ?

Comment: Nope, hint : use masters theorem

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful After applying masters theorem, a = 6, b = 2 so log6/log2 = 2.5846. Which is greater than c = 1. So wont the answer be O(n^2.25)

Comment: @Rockstar - SORRY, i had evaluated considering a = 2(my mistake, I didn't see carefully). Yes, the complexity would be O(n^2.25) --- the same what you've mentioned. Thanks for notifying.

Comment: in the assignment we are not allowed to solve by the masters theorem because it is not covered yet.

So can you help me in finding the complexity via telescoping

Comment: @Mira - So you should solve it by expanding all along.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful can you help me in expanding

Comment: @Mira - Yeah,consider O(n) = cn, that would solve your problem easily.